# Can't launch LibreOffice 4.4 on Linux Mint 17

Tags: installation, linux-mint, libreoffice

Uninstalled LibreOffice 4.2, downloaded the 64-bit LibreOffice 4.4 tar files and extracted them all into a folder on the 64-bit Cinnamon Mint 17 desktop, then installed, as per the README, from a terminal window in that folder with

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Now, its icons appear in the Cinnamon menu, but when I try to start any of them, I get

```
LibreOffice 4.4 - Fatal Error
The application cannot be started.
User application could not be completed.
```

What more information would be useful, and where do I go from here? TY.

Comment: Try starting the program with: `strace Writer`. That should give a lot more information. To log the output to a file `strace Writer 2> logfile` If short, include it here... Just a stupid question: did you install the correct version? I mean 64 or 32 bits?

Comment: Did yo test with strace? I think that would be interesting.

Comment: No, did not, once a solution was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by deleting the old profile with

```
mv ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/  ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user_old/
```

Works very well now.

Thanks to http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/users/5296/karolus/ for the solution.